# Use variable inside the regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
var string = "I put putty on the computer. putty, PUT do I"

var uniques = {};

var result = (string.match(/\b\w*put\w*\b/ig) || []).filter(function(item) {
   item = item.toLowerCase();
   return uniques[item] ? false : (uniques[item] = true);
});

document.write( result.join(", ") );
```

Here i want pass a variable inside the expression

here i have pass a value **'put'** and get answer. But **i have to use variable** for this value.

I have tried   **string.match(/\b\w*{+put+}\w*\b/ig**

Can you share your answers

Comment: Use `new RegExp("")` it can take the regex expression as a string so variable can be easily added to it.

Comment: i can't understand please provide some sample

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript

Answer (score 4):

You should create a specific [Regular Expression object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to use with the `.match()` function. This way you can create your regex with a string and insert the variable when creating it:

```
var changing_value = "put";
var re = new RegExp("\\b\\w*" + changing_value + "\\w*\\b", "ig");
```

Note that the ignore case (`i`) and global (`g`) modifiers are specified as the second parameter to the `RegExp` constructor instead of part of the actual expression. Also that you need to escape the `\` character inside the constructor [because \ is also an escape character in strings.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backslash)

Another thing to note is that you don't need the `/`delimiters`/` at the start and end of the expression when using the `Regexp` constructor.

Now you can use the Regexp object in your call to `.match()`:

```
string.match( re )
```

As a final note, I *don't recommend* that you use the name `string` as a variable name... As you can see from the syntax highlighting, `string` is a reserved word and it is not recommended to use names of built-in types for variable names as they may cause confusion.

Comment: For `RegExp` constructor all escape collections should be escaped with extra backslash (``\\``).

Comment: @Bala - I know :/ I know... It actually happened the other way around... I posted the answer first then realized that it's probably a duplicate.

Comment: @Bala - [it's not such a bad thing though...](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: @VisioN- I did miss it :) Thanks for your feedback! Corrections and reference added.

Comment: this answer is not working.can you share the another answers with full coding

Comment: @PeterAbraham- "not working" is not specific enough. If you have a specific problem with the solution, please describe it here so that we may help you appropriately.